# How to get profiling output of java programs running on Tomcat using java -prof option?

Tags: java, tomcat, profiling

in java programs, running the programs with java profiler will generate profiling output
Ex-  java -prof classfile_name

How to get same profiling output of java programs running on Tomcat?

I want to get an profiling output like this

count callee caller time ,  like this in profiling output

1 java.util.LinkedHashMap.init()V java.util.HashMap.(IF)V 0

Can you tell me how to get an output like this for programs running on Tomcat?

Comment: [`jvisualvm`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html) can attach to a running tomcat process.

Answer (score 2):

Tomcat is also just a Java application, so you can add the same VM parameters by defining the `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable in `startup.bat/startup.sh` of your Tomcat distribution.

However, I would really recommend to use a real profiler, there are several free and commercial alternatives. The major free one is [visualvm](http://visualvm.java.net/) and as a commercial solution I  recommend [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) (disclaimer: my company develops that tool).

In those profilers, look for the "Hot spot" views which will show you the kind of information that you are looking for.