# Tomcat server starts slowly

Tags: java, performance, tomcat, startup

I have a situation where Tomcat is starting with my java application, but then hangs for several minutes before continuing. Startup logs do not seem to point to anything specific.

Is there a way that I could debug this?

Comment: plz, define the problem well like which version of tomcat you used, what is the configuration etc.

Comment: You will need to turn on fine/debug logs to see where it is waiting. Is the CPU working all the time, or is perhaps waiting for some connection?

Comment: Is it tomcat that's has slow startup? or your application? If it's tomcat I would just lower the log-level and look at the timestamps for whats using the most time: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html

Comment: if most of the code is not yours, un familiar, u can do analysis by attaching profiler. see https://www.yourkit.com/docs/java/help/attach_agent.jsp and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479715/how-to-get-profiling-output-of-java-programs-running-on-tomcat-using-java-prof

Comment: Which version of tomcat you are using .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very broad. We have nothing to work with here in providing an answer.

All I can give you is generic debugging advice.

- Add printouts into your web application's startup sequence. Watch
  them and see where it hangs.
- Try commenting out part for part of the start-up until you notice that
  start-up is suddenly sped up, the last bit you commented out should
  be the faulty one.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered once a problem where starting Tomcat on a dedicated server also took ages. My problem was that the entropy source that is used to initialize SecureRandom was short of entropy.

It's a known bug: https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo/FasterStartUp#Entropy_Source

If this is your problem, known workarounds are:

Set the following system property: -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom

or

Use 'new SecureRandom()' instead of 'SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG")' (if you have this in your code  [[source]](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6202721)).